# Is there a JSON equivalent of the html_strip filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

We receive data from application forms in JSON and need to be able to search on it - but only the text entered by the user. Some of our data from other sources comes in as XML and this is fine - the html_strip (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html) character filter does the job.

But is there an equivalent for JSON - you send serialized JSON as text and it strips out the tags just leaving the data?

A very simplistic example:

The application form sends back this data:

```
{
  "ed_hist1": "Glasgow High School",
  "ed_hist2": "Edinburgh University"
}
```

This gets serialized and added to our document as a text field:

```
{
  "Type": "applicationform",
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Margaret Blenkinsop",
  "Email": "JohnB232@myCompany.COM",
  "Text": "{\"ed_hist1\":\"Glasgow High School\",\"ed_hist2\":\"Edinburgh University\"}"
}
```

And that gets sent to ES.

When I search the text field I don't want to be able to find "ed_hist1" or "ed_hist2" only "Glasgow High School" and ""Edinburgh University".

Or is the only way to pre-process the JSON? (Which is fine but I don't want to manually code something if ES will take care of it for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution #1

There are a couple ways of accomplishing what you want. The most "idiomatic" way would be to pre-process the JSON coming from you application, transforming the JSON doc you have to a list.

EG:

```
{
  "ed_hist1": "Glasgow High School",
  "ed_hist2": "Edinburgh University"
}
```

becomes

```
[
  "Glasgow High School",
  "Edinburgh University"
]
```

And then your document would look as follows:

```
{
  "Type": "applicationform",
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Margaret Blenkinsop",
  "Email": "JohnB232@myCompany.COM",
  "Text": ["Glasgow High School", "Edinburgh University"]
}
```

You could then search the `Text` field for the `ed_hist` you are looking for and have documents returned that match your query etc. This is the most simple solution for your case, but there are other ways of structuring your data depending on what questions you want to ask of it.

#### Solution #2

You seem to be thinking a fair bit about keeping the original JSON document as text in a field as part of another document. Without additional context, I do not particularly like this solution but I assume you have your reasons. For this second, not  recommended use case, I would use char filters in addition to `store`ing your original field value. The process would look like this:

```
index document
original documented `store`d
custom char filter strips out the unwanted JSON language characters
text indexed
```

At query time you can get back the original stored value, but also leverage the "full text" search on the text contained in the JSON document after the characters have been stripped. I really believe you can get more out of your data if you do a solution #1 variant. Stripping HTML for text search is a good idea to search through markup documents, but stripping JSON makes less sense as JSON is ES's bread and butter, and will give you more tools to work with as JSON.

EDIT: I forgot to link to the `store` documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html

EDIT #2: Of additional note is the _source field which is enabled by default: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html Your original JSON document lives there, for free, as well. This can get you back the original document you sent to ES, while still giving you the more idiomatic data structure in the DB.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks a lot for your reply. I must admit option 1 hadn't occurred to me and you're quite right - it looks a lot nicer. Our solution has been running live for a good few months now and has really "settled down" - it's rare for us to have problems with it so everyone (me included) would be reluctant to change the interface between the back and front end to accommodate an array rather than a single Text field. Hindsight .... I'm interested in the char filter idea but wouldn't it be too complex to set up a char filter? What would it look like? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html Your char filter could be a simple mapping filter where you simply replace each JSON langauge token, like `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `"` with nothing, and you have some sanitized text. You can test your filters out using the `_analyze` endpoing just like in the docs there. Good luck!